# How do I check the call order of different functions in C

Tags: c

in order to set a certain variable (MyVariable) to "TRUE" I have to check that a specific function call order was respected within a system.
For example, I have different functions within the system:

```
uint8 myFunction1()
{
    if (...)
    {
    return NOT_OK
    }
    else     
    {
    return OK
    }
}

uint8 myFunction2()
{
    if (...)
    {
    return NOT_OK
    }
    else     
    {
    return OK
    }
}


uint8 myFunction3()
{
    if (...)
    {
    return NOT_OK
    }
    else     
    {
    return OK
    }
}
```

MyVariable = TRUE only if:

1. OK == myFunction1
2. OK == myFunction2
3. OK == myFunction3

exactly this call order was respected.
How to check the call order in C but without touching the body of the functions (like setting some flags´etc.)?

I'm still beginner and experimenting with C :)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of "state machines"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: 1. wrap the function in custom functions where you set flags with timestamp. 2. when setting myVariable compare timestamps and function returns. 3. This  is C. There is no other way then to implement this yourself.

Comment: Generally, you may want to look at something like [GNU Cflow](https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/) to chart the control flow within your source file(s) as your programs grown in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly an "XY problem". That is, you think saving the call order is the solution to your actual problem, but your actual problem might be to ensure that the functions can't be called in the wrong order in the first place.

So the most correct way to fix this is to remake the program design. Someone mentioned state machines as one solution. Another solution might be something like an array of function pointers (which is a common implementation of state machines).

---

That being said, you *can* do something artificial to track the call order, though I wouldn't really recommend it. Example:

```
#define CALL_ORDER_N 3

const char* call_order [CALL_ORDER_N] = {NULL};
size_t call_order_i = 0;


static void save_call (const char* func)
{
  call_order[call_order_i] = func;
  call_order_i++;
  if(call_order_i == CALL_ORDER_N)
  {
    call_order_i = 0;
  } 
}
```

Where `call_order` saves the 3 last function calls as pointers to string literals. The function `save_call` updates this array, by passing the `__func__` constant to it from each function. `__func__` is guaranteed to work like a `static const char[]` so this is safe. You'd do something like this:

```
void myFunction1 (void)
{
  save_call(__func__);
  ...
}

void myFunction2 (void)
{
  save_call(__func__);
  ...
}

void myFunction3 (void)
{
  save_call(__func__);
  ...
}
```

And then go through the calls to see if they were in the correct order:

```
static bool is_call_order_ok (void)
{
  const char* expected_order [CALL_ORDER_N] = 
  {
    "myFunction1",
    "myFunction2",
    "myFunction3"
  };

  size_t co_i = call_order_i;

  for(size_t i=0; i<CALL_ORDER_N; i++)
  {
    if(strcmp(call_order[co_i], expected_order[i])==0)
    {
      co_i++;
      if(co_i == CALL_ORDER_N)
      {
        co_i = 0;
      } 
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CALL_ORDER_N 3

const char* call_order [CALL_ORDER_N] = {NULL};
size_t call_order_i = 0;


static void save_call (const char* func)
{
  call_order[call_order_i] = func;
  call_order_i++;
  if(call_order_i == CALL_ORDER_N)
  {
    call_order_i = 0;
  } 
}

static bool is_call_order_ok (void)
{
  const char* expected_order [CALL_ORDER_N] = 
  {
    "myFunction1",
    "myFunction2",
    "myFunction3"
  };

  size_t co_i = call_order_i;

  for(size_t i=0; i<CALL_ORDER_N; i++)
  {
    if(strcmp(call_order[co_i], expected_order[i])==0)
    {
      co_i++;
      if(co_i == CALL_ORDER_N)
      {
        co_i = 0;
      } 
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}


void myFunction1 (void)
{
  save_call(__func__);
}


void myFunction2 (void)
{
  save_call(__func__);
}


void myFunction3 (void)
{
  save_call(__func__);
}



int main (void)
{
  printf("Call 1,2,3: ");
  myFunction1();
  myFunction2();
  myFunction3();
  printf(is_call_order_ok() ? "Ok\n" : "Failed\n");

  printf("Call 3,2,1: ");
  myFunction3();
  myFunction2();
  myFunction1();
  printf(is_call_order_ok() ? "Ok\n" : "Failed\n");

  printf("Call 1,1,1: ");
  myFunction1();
  myFunction1();
  myFunction1();
  printf(is_call_order_ok() ? "Ok\n" : "Failed\n");

  return 0;
}
```

---

The advanced, more professional version of the above, would be to cook together a mini-API with a single function, in order to give private encapsulation to every single variable. The function `save_call` would then be a multi-purpose function, that can be used to register expected call order, save function calls, as well as verify if the current registered order is ok.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CALL_ORDER_N 3

static bool save_call (const char* func, bool verify)
{
  bool result;

  static const char* call_order [CALL_ORDER_N] = {NULL};
  static size_t call_order_i = 0;
  static const char* expected_order [CALL_ORDER_N] = {NULL};

  size_t i = call_order_i;

  if(verify)                           // special case, verify the order
  {
    for(size_t expected=0; expected<CALL_ORDER_N; expected++)
    {
      if(call_order[i] == expected_order[expected])
      {
        i++;
        if(i == CALL_ORDER_N)
        {
          i = 0;
        } 
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  if(expected_order[i] == NULL)        // register order of calls
  {
    expected_order[i] = func;
    result = true;
  }
  else                                 // save calls
  {
    call_order[i] = func;
    result = false;
  }

  call_order_i++;
  if(call_order_i == CALL_ORDER_N)
  {
    call_order_i = 0;
  } 

  return result;
}


void myFunction1 (void)
{
  if(save_call(__func__, false))
    return ;
  printf("Execute stuff in %s.\n", __func__);
}


void myFunction2 (void)
{
  if(save_call(__func__, false))
    return ;
  printf("Execute stuff in %s.\n", __func__);
}


void myFunction3 (void)
{
  if(save_call(__func__, false))
    return ;
  printf("Execute stuff in %s.\n", __func__);
}



int main (void)
{
  /* register call order: */
  myFunction1();
  myFunction2();
  myFunction3();


  printf("Call 1,2,3:\n");
  myFunction1();
  myFunction2();
  myFunction3();
  printf(save_call(NULL, true) ? "Ok\n\n" : "Failed\n\n");

  printf("Call 3,2,1:\n");
  myFunction3();
  myFunction2();
  myFunction1();
  printf(save_call(NULL, true) ? "Ok\n\n" : "Failed\n\n");

  printf("Call 1,1,1:\n");
  myFunction1();
  myFunction1();
  myFunction1();
  printf(save_call(NULL, true) ? "Ok\n\n" : "Failed\n\n");

  return 0;
}
```

`save_call` should of course be properly placed in a .h/.c file pair of its own.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct and portable way. That being said, debuggers are great at breaking execution flow when a function is reached, so you could either use a debugger, or use debugging functions to be warned when the functions are called (unfortunately nothing portable here).

Alternatively, some linkers allow to hide some identifiers and replace them so with custom (and advanced) link options you could replace all call to those functions with calls to custom wrappers. But here again it would only makes sense for a specific implementation so it is not a C way either.

Anyway, this is such an uncommon requirement that I cannot imagine the actual reasonning behind. Maybe you could give more context about your real problem...

Comment: Thanks for you info. But debuggers are great when debugging. I need to check the condition during the run time of the system. Trying to be more precise:My requirement is that I can change to an specific state within my system only if first myFunction1() than myFunction2() and than myFunction3() is called.